# How can I get sIFR to render the .sIFR-alternate correctly with FlashBlock enabled?

Tags: flash, sifr, sifr3

So I've looked this up in a few different places, and the only answer I've seen is "style the `span.sIFR-alternate` element". Problem is, if I apply any styles to that element that will actually have it appear & be placed correctly, it shows up alongside the sIFR text when FlashBlock isn't present (e.g. in Safari/IE) or is disabled.

Here's the default styles for `.sIFR-alternate`:

```
.sIFR-alternate {
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    display: block;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

And I'm adding these:

```
span.sIFR-alternate {
    font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-size: 24px;
    line-height: 14px;
    color: #000000;
    padding: 0;
    margin-top:12px;
    margin-bottom:7px;
}
```

What am I missing?

Otherwise though, sIFR is working well.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure? That doesn't quite add up. Try adding the other styles property by property to see what triggers it.

Comment: And… now I see `.sIFR-alternate` correctly… very odd. I fiddled with this for almost two hours just a few days ago! It seems like Flashblock is adding inline styles to the element itself now, that wasn't happening before.

Oh well.